# How to force a fixed column width with a Bootstrap grid and keep the other ones fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I want to create the grid layout shown on the following image.

I would like to have a sidebar with a fixed with of 330px, no matter which screen sizes and keep everything inside `#page-content` re sizable depending on the resolution of my visitor's screen. [image: grid]

How can I achieve the layout shown on the image? If I do the following:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="page-content">
   <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-10">...</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" id="sidebar">
   ...
</div>
```

and try to fix the width of `#sidebar` with `width="330px";` for smaller screen sizes, the content will shift to the right, where it can't be seen. Since Bootstrap assigns `width: 16.66666667%;` to `.col-md-2`, it seems like I would have to get rid the grid system for the higher level divs, `#page-content` and `#sidebar`. But then, how can I make sure `#page-conten`t fills the remaining space at the left of `#sidebar`.

Comment: I've managed to lock in a column's width by setting both min-width and max-width to the same value. Works like a charm. Using Boostrap 4.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Bootstrap's grid were meant to be fluid so they're supposed to change as the screen changes size.

For your desired layout, you can make it happen using `display: flex` or `display:table` instead. I'm going to go with `display:table` for my example since there's more support for it than the flexbox.

You will need to change your HTML to something like:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="blue">test</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="green">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="gold">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS I used:

```
.page {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.page-content,
.sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 330px;
}
.blue,
.green,
.gold {
  height: 50px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.gold {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

You can checkout the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/qjutpze4/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't meet his requirement, he wants to align on the same row but your's display in two rows.

Comment: @BradyHuang this display is only in two rows when the width is less than 1009 pixels! I don't think there's any alternative though, because if the screen is narrow, there's nowhere else for other columns to go than underneath each other!

Answer (score 76):

Bootstrap 4.0 beta:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col my-sidebar">
      <h2>LEFT</h2>
      <h6>(FIXED 230px COLUMN)</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h1>CENTER (FLUID COLUMN)</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col my-sidebar">
      <h2>RIGHT</h2>
      <h6>(FIXED 230px COLUMN)</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-sidebar {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 230px;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
    background-color: greenyellow; 
} 

@media (max-width: 690px) {
  .my-sidebar {
    display: none; 
  } 
}
```

Live example here: https://www.codeply.com/view/PHYTWFDFRU

In this example fixed columns will disappear if the browser window width becomes less than 690px. If you want them to be always visible remove the second css-block with **@media** entirely.

Comment: For the perfection of it, may I suggest using the classes **d-none d-sm-block** (in the respective order) instead of using the @media rule? the **d-sm-block** triggers at a 576px width, which is according to the Bootstrap 4 device scheme. You can read more about it at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Sorry, I have quit web development more than a year ago and I don't have time right now to get into your suggestion carefully. I think my example gives an idea of how CSS works without having to know what these Bootstrap classes mean. But if you'd like you can edit my answer and add your alternative example.

Answer (score 46):

Simply fix the width of the element you want fixed and don't add a measure to your bootstrap column (like col-8), by doing this it will take the remaining space automatically.

In my case I only had two elements on the row. Hope this helps.

```
.fixed{
    width: 300px;
}

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="fixed">
                Fixed Width
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Fluid
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In my case it makes rows out of my columns, meaning, if I replace all `div class="col">` with  `div class="fixed">`, all cells are located underneath one another. Sorry, if this is a stupid comment, just started a little side work and haven't looked into html/cms since ages.

Comment: @w461 I had the same problem, but I had forgotten the css class .fixed, which, by the way, is provided in the answer with 300px width as an example.

Comment: This worked perfect for me to fix the first column and make the 2nd one width variable.